# SPARX Enterprise Architect. Add Note to Diagram with formatted text using Scripting

Tags: javascript, scripting, rtf, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to add a note to a diagram with formatted text similar to the Diagram Properties

[image]

I tried

```
dgmElement.Notes = currentPackage.Elements.AddNew("","Text");
```

and

```
dgmElement.Notes = currentPackage.Elements.AddNew("", "Note");


dgmElement.Notes 
  = "Classification:" + "UNCLASSIFIED" + String.fromCharCode(13) 
  + "Model Type:    " + "SV1-SFFSESVSE SEASDEAER" + String.fromCharCode(13) 
  + "Diagram Status:" + "APPPROVED" + String.fromCharCode(13) 
  + "Date Modified: " + currentDiagram.ModifiedDate + String.fromCharCode(13) ;
```

but neither returns the desired format.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Larry. Please clarify your question. It is not very clear what the problem is and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Using only Carriage Return (13) for newlines seems weird. I've only ever seen Linefeed(10) or the combination of Carriage Return(13) and LineFeed(10)

Answer (score 2):

Both are possible. EA renders a note frame around a note. Text will appear without a frame.

Formatting like in the diagram properties can be achieved by adding tab chars. For "advanced" formatting like bold text you need to use the repository operations `GetFieldFromFormat` and `GetFormatFromField` (see the help) to convert the text from and to EA's internal memo format.

This is a Python example but you can probably translate it to your target language:

```py
dia = rep.getDiagramByGUID("{81B59BAD-B22F-4375-AA73-C489958A3D6B}")
pck = rep.getPackageByID(dia.packageID)

text = pck.elements.addNew("", "Text")
text.notes = rep.getFieldFromFormat("TXT", "a\tb\r\nc\td")
# note the \r\n for a newline. Windoze
text.update
dobj = dia.diagramObjects.addNew("l=10;r=110;t=-20;b=-80", "") # coord. on diagram
dobj.elementID = text.elementId
dobj.update
rep.reloadDiagram (dia.diagramID)
```

In the above example the text could as well have been assigned directly to `text.notes` since it's a simple case. However, you could as well supply rtf or html this way and txt would be formatted regarding special chars.

Comment: I did this 
 dgmElement = currentPackage.Elements.AddNew("","Note");
 dgmElement.Notes = "<p>Classification:      " + "<b><font color='#0000ff'>UNCLASSIFIED</font></b></p>"
   +  "<p>Diagram Title:     " + "<b><font>" + currentDiagram.Name + "</font></b></p>"    
I like the \t  tab.    
I will read up on the .getFieldFromFormat()    

Thanks

Comment: I don't use Javascript, and don't know if it supports `\t` but would be surprised if it wouldn't. Your string needs the HTML conversion. You can't assign the notes to the dgmObj. It's a representation of the base Text element where the notes are held.

Answer (score -1):

```
  text = pck.elements.addNew( "", "Text" )
  text.Subtype = 18
  text.Update()
  # coord. on diagram
  dobj = aNode.diagramObjects.addNew( "l=10;r=110;t=-20;b=-80", "" )  
  dobj.elementID = text.elementId
  dobj.Update()
  getRepo().reloadDiagram( aNode.diagramID )
```

In additional, to add a standard **EA diagram note** which contains diagram info can be used a code above (Python)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).